# How to keep controls disabled on page refresh in aspx page?

Tags: asp.net

I am disabling few textboxes and submit button on an aspx page when I click on submit button, but I observed when I refresh/reload the browser, the controls are getting enabled again including submit button.
I searched for it but could not find any reason/solution. Can anyone give useful information?

Answer (score 1):

When you refresh page the html for page is generated for the first time and it does not have the changes you did on last postback. All you can do to `save the state of controls in some persistent medium like database or files and use it when page is refreshed`.

*You can try putting the state of one control in session and get back in page load just for the sake of experiment if it works for you then you can store it in database of whereever you like*

**Changing state on button click**

```
Textbox1.Enabled = false;
Session["Textbox1Enabled"] = false;
```

**In Page_LoadEvent**

```
if(Session["Textbox1Enabled"] != null)
{
    Textbox1.Enabled =  bool.Parse(Session["Textbox1Enabled"].ToString());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try `Enabled="false"` and `IsPostBack section` and `EnableViewState="true"`

```
if(!IsPostBack)
{
  //Bind your textbow
  yourTextBox.Enabled=false;
  yourTextBox.EnableViewState=true;
}
```

Nota : you persist your controls with ViewState

Answer (score 0):

When you refresh/reload the page, you are requesting a new version of it, so any state you had will be lost.

To achieve what you are trying to achieve, you will need to actively track the session on the server, and disable controls based on this.